# Does IFTTT work with Google Hangouts?

Tags: if-this-then-that, google-hangouts

The IFTTT site has a [GTalk channel](https://ifttt.com/google_talk).

Is that the same as Hangouts?

In the GMail web page, we only have Hangouts, not chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not the same as Hangouts. Gtalk is more or less replaced by Hangouts. The IFTTT channel was quite limited in any case, but it won't work with Hangouts at all.

Comment: IFTTT will remove the Google Talk Channel: "On March 21, all Recipes that use the Google Talk Channel will be removed. As Google Talk has transitioned to Hangouts, the Channel has become less relevant."

Answer (score 3):

It's true that IFTTT's GTalk channel doesn't work with Hangouts, but I found a similar service, [Zapier](https://zapier.com), that does.

It's geared more towards business users, so the connected services include more service apps and less social media, and the free version is limited to 5 recepies (or Zaps), but it's something.